# How to display a pdf file on tool tip using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have a link as:

`<a href="pdf/testpdf.pdf">PDF</a>`

I want to set a tooltip for this link and in tooltip display the same pdf file.

That means i want to display the contents of `testpdf.pdf` file in tooltip when mouse over the link.

I searched that for in google, but there have no link siutable for me.

There have a lot of model for image ,text in tooltip.

How can I do this?

Anyboady have any solution?

Comment: What's about `<a title="testpdf.pdf" href="pdf/testpdf.pdf">PDF</a>`?

Comment: i need to diplay the contents not the title....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Displaying a PDF generally involves launching a browser plugin, such as Adobe Reader, which has its own menu bar, toolbar, and so on. Cramming that into a small space like a tooltip probably isn't very practical.

You'd be better off rendering a thumbnail image — maybe use a PDF library on the server for this — and showing *that* in the tooltip.

Comment: Exactly. And displaying the whole PDF in a tooltip may not be the best idea, because you can't enter the tooltip to scroll for example. And you also can't be sure about the zoom factor and so on. I also think that the only solution could be displaying it in an iframe - which still could lead to download the file in certain browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

It renders PDF files onto canvas..

But in my opinion it is not a good solution at all, when the PDF is big, it will take some time to load it into the tooltip..Better is to create a thumbnail on the server and display it as a standard image..
[Here](http://www.deanblog.co.uk/article/10/upload-a-pdf-and-create-thumbnail-image-in-php) is how to do that with PHP

Answer (score 1):

I think that requires the browser to have a plugin to display PDF inline instead of downloading it. Once this is ensured, you can set the target of your tooltip to the URL pointing to PDF. What tooltip library are you using, btw?